# Umbraco member select error

Tags: umbraco, members

When I select a member it comes with this error this just happend this morning.

this is confusing, maybe someone know whats happening.

I got this error see link

http://gyazo.com/08c4a5a86c8ca9dfe0f12336594ebb4b

And Im working on umbraco 7.0.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out that you cant have a membergroups with '.' and ',' in umbraco 7.0.3

So the error comes when you select the user and it loads all the membergroups.